# Request node sync

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, cheerio

Somebody make this following code without assync? 
I'd like o code below execute pass to pass in sync.

```
var url = 'http://xxxxxx.com/';
var cont = 1;

while(cont != 10){

    request(url + cont,function(err, res, html){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var list = $('li');
        list.each(function(idx, el){
            var url2 = $(el).children('a').attr('href');
            request(url2, function(error, response, body){
                //I Want execute this response for continue
            });
        });
    });
    cont++;
}
```

Comment: i think liitle more explanation is required about the requirement

Comment: You can't do synchronous networking in node.js.  If you describe what you are actually trying to accomplish with your code in words, we can help with how you would program that using asynchronous methods in node.js.  Your current code doesn't actually do anything with a result so we can't tell from that code what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm expecting request call in only 2 level if you need n level hen this should not work . Then we need recursion in place of it.
Let me know if some issue :)

```
async.times(10, function(n, next) {
        request(url + cont,function(err, res, html){
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var list = $('li');
                async.each(list, function(el, cbk){
                    var url2 = $(el).children('a').attr('href');
                    request(url2, function(error, response, body){
                        //I Want execute this response for continue
                        cbk(err, data);
                    });
                }, next);
            });
    }, function(err, users) {
        //data is 2D array
        //err is error if any
    });
```